# How to get Zoom value in scroll viewer in C# wpf Kinect SDK 2.0?

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollview, kinect, kinect-sdk

I have recently started using the Kinect SDK 2.0 and am focusing on a zoom and pan functionality, as in the Control Basics-WPF sample.

I have got the zoom and pan functionality up and running. The problem is that I wish to access the value of the amount of zoom which has been performed by the Pinch zoom gesture.

Here is my xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ImageNav.NavigationImage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:k="http://schemas.microsoft.com/kinect/2014"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignWidth="1200"
      d:DesignHeight="700"
      >

    <Grid Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <ScrollViewer Name="scrollViewer" Grid.Row="0" 
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      k:KinectRegion.IsHorizontalRailEnabled="true" k:KinectRegion.IsVerticalRailEnabled="true"
                      k:KinectRegion.ZoomMode="Enabled">
            <Image Name="navigationImage" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5" />
        </ScrollViewer>
        <TextBox x:Name="ZoomTextBox" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Zoom: 100%" IsEnabled="False" Panel.ZIndex="10" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="20"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I would have wanted there to be something like `k:KinectRegion.ZoomFactor`, but that isnt available. I've also tried to see what changes in the UI elements when I perform the zoom gesture, by writing the `Height` and `ActualHeight` properties of the `ScrollViewer scrollViewer` and `Image navigationImage` to a log file, but they show no change whatsoever.

When I perform the zoom gesture, I would like to get the value of zoom i.e. the current height and width of the image with respect to the original height and width.

Comment: Can you get to the current transform that is applied and deduce from the matrix maybe the zoom factor instead?

Answer (score 5):

This has nothing to do with Kinect SDK, this is more of a `ScrollViewer` zooming issue. There is no `k:KinectRegion.ZoomFactor` because zooming doesn't change the actual size of the image, it only performs some layout transformations, therefore you can get the zooming factor from `LayoutTransform` property of your `Image`.

Something like the following code should get the zooming factor:

**UserControl.Code:**

```
    public NavigationImage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        _zoom = 1.0;
    }

    double _zoom;
    public string ZoomPercentage
    {
        get
        {
            return _zoom * 100 + "%";
        }
    }

    private void scrollViewer_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Delta > 0)
        {
            _zoom += 0.1;
        }
        else
        {
            _zoom -= 0.1;
        }

        ScaleTransform scale = new ScaleTransform(_zoom, _zoom);
        navigationImage.LayoutTransform = scale;
        OnPropertyChanged("ZoomPercentage");
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

**UserControl.Xaml:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="ImageNav.NavigationImage"  ...    >

    <Grid Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <ScrollViewer Name="scrollViewer" Grid.Row="0" PreviewMouseWheel="scrollViewer_MouseWheel"
        ....
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      k:KinectRegion.IsHorizontalRailEnabled="true" k:KinectRegion.IsVerticalRailEnabled="true"
                      k:KinectRegion.ZoomMode="Enabled"
                      >
            <Image Name="navigationImage" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <TextBox x:Name="ZoomTextBox" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding ZoomPercentage, Mode=OneWay}" .... />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```